# Modify PDF to add buttons using javascript in ionic cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, jspdf

I have a magazine view app that is intended to watch magazines

a magazine is an array of existing urls each makes one page of the magazine
so if a magazine has ten pages i will have ten different pdfs.

I  want to download the first one (using Cordova file transfer http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) and later view it (using cordova fileOpener)

My question is how can i allow the user to pass to the next page from within the pdf application (since it will open an individual pdf it will not show the other unrelated pages).

i was thinking adding buttons on the pdf but i have no idea how to tackle it using js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for our company app we use [angular-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/winkerVSbecks/angular-pdf-viewer)

It is very simple and easy to use, it will allow you to easily add buttons and connect them to the directives functions. It can even display page numbers and rotate pages if needed.

Just inject the module after including the js in you index.html file

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['pdf']);
```

then drop the directive on your page. You can also set up two way databinding for your array of magazines.

```
<pdf-viewer
    delegate-handle="my-pdf-container"
    url="pdfUrl"
    scale="1"
    show-toolbar="true"
    headers="{ 'x-you-know-whats-awesome': 'EVERYTHING' }"></pdf-viewer>
```

Here is a list of methods that you can use (you can also have multiple pdf-viewers by using different handles

```
pdfDelegate.$getByHandle('my-pdf-container').zoomIn();
•prev
•next
•zoomIn(amount) default amount = 0.2
•zoomOut(amount) default amount = 0.2
•zoomTo(amount)
•rotate (clockwise by 90 degrees)
•getPageCount
•getCurrentPage
•goToPage(pageNumber)
•load
```

to change the pdf loaded you can either change the pdfUrl with two way databinding or you can use the pdf delegate handle:

```
pdfDelegate
    .$getByHandle('my-pdf-container')
    .load('url-of-the-new-file.pdf');
```

EDIT: 
sorry I gave you one of the many pdf modules, this is actually the one we used, the other one may be better if you need different viewers though (more than one) here is the one we used: https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf

here is the pdf viewer on the page.

```
<ion-view>
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
        <button ng-click="$ionicGoBack()" class="button button-clear button-light icon-left ion-chevron-left">Go Back</button>
    </div>
    <div class="has-header">
        <ng-pdf template-url="components/pdfviewer/viewer.html" canvasid="pdf" scale="0.675">
        </ng-pdf>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

then we have a viewer.html template

```
<div ng-show="notLoaded" class=" center bar bar-subheader">
    <h1 class="title">Loading PDF...</h1>
</div>
<div class="tabs tabs-icon-left">
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goPrevious()">
        <i class="icon ion-arrow-left-c"></i>
        Prev
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goNext()">
        <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-c"></i>
        Next
    </a>
</div>
 <ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" class="has-header">
        <canvas class="padding" id="pdf" class="rotate0"></canvas>
    </ion-scroll>
```

here is the controller code from their demo:

```
   angular.module('testApp', ['pdf']).controller('AppCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'pdfDelegate',
    function ($scope, pdfDelegate, $log) {
        $scope.relativity = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/149125/relativity.pdf';
        $scope.material = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/149125/material-design-2.pdf';
        $scope.pdfUrl = $scope.material;
    }
]);
```

Comment: Whow this looks awesome. I'll give it a run and update

Comment: just fyi we but the pdf-viewer on a page and then had a footer bar with a button bar for all the buttons. I can add a photo if you want to see what it looks like. Also check the edit, I added some code that we used to make pinch zoom and stuff work as well.

Comment: I tested it and i like it a lot , one small thing ,how can i find the reference name to the module? when i try to inject in my controller pdfDelegate or $pdfDelegate in my controller im getting unknown provider error

Comment: did you include all the dependincies?
<script src="bower_components/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-pdf-viewer/dist/angular-pdf-viewer.min.js"></script>
and then they say Inject the pdfDelegate service into your controller. You can then fetch an instance using it's delegate handle and call methods on it:

Comment: also make sure you injected pdf into your moduel. var app = angular.module('App', ['pdf']);

Comment: pdf is loaded to the app , its working , i just dont know how to reference the pdf module inside the controller... (what to to nject to the controller)

Comment: It looks like it is just pdfDelegate, but you have to grab onto a instance of it using the handle of your viewer. pdfDelegate.$getByHandle('my-pdf-container').zoomIn();